# Is rs.EOF = True possible? If yes in which condition it is possible in vb6.0?

Tags: vb6

```
With rs
    .CursorType = adOpenStatic 'I tried all types
    .LockType = adLockOptimistic 'I tried all types
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .Open com
End With

while rs.EOF = False
    if val(t1.text) = rs.fields(1) then
        msgbox "Reg.no. " & rs.fields(1) & " is Already in database"
        'Our Searching work in db is done here, we want to close this while loop by code, so i used below
        rs.EOF = True 'here compiler error gives "can't assign to read-only property"
    else
        rs.movenext
    end if
wend

'here want to do " if not val(t1.text) = rs.fields(1) " operation
```

Pls help to assign read/write property, if it can't pls tell me the another solution to close 'this condition/while loop...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't set rs.EOF=True because is a read-only Property, but you can escape from the loop.
Try something like that:

```
Do while Not rs.EOF
    if val(t1.text) = rs.fields(1) then
        msgbox "Reg.no. " & rs.fields(1) & " is Already in database"
        Exit Do
    end if
    rs.movenext
Loop
rs.close
```